# what type does my object query return?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, types

```
Public Function List_category() As Myobj 
Dim query = From subcat In _dataContext.subcategories, _ 
cat In _dataContext.categories _ 
Where subcat.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID _
                Select New Myobj() With { _
                .SubcatId = subcat.SubCategoryID, _
                .SubcatName = subcat.SubCategoryName, _
                .CatId = cat.CategoryID, _
                .CatName = cat.CategoryName _
                }
return ?????????
End Function
```

Public Class Myobj

```
Private m_SubcatId As Integer
Private m_SubcatName As String
Private m_catId As Integer
Private m_catName As String

Public Property SubcatId() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_SubcatId
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_SubcatId = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SubcatName() As String
    Get
        Return m_SubcatName
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_SubcatName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property CatId() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_catId
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_catId = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property CatName() As String
    Get
        Return m_catName
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_catName = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

doesnt works!!!!

It Says 'Set' accessor of property 'SubcatName' is not accessible.

Comment: Easy on the question marks, just think calm, cool, rational thoughts and we'll get through this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom type and modify your `select` to instantiate that for the return.  Take a look here: [Linq To Sql return from function as IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460831/linq-to-sql-return-from-function-as-iqueryablet)

Comment: Um, ok.  My VB may be a little syntactically off, but this is the general idea (note that you'll need to create the MyObject class, of course): Return From subcat In _dataContext.subcategories, cat In _dataContext.categories Where subcat.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID Select New MyObject() With {.SubCategoryID = subcat.SubCategoryId, .SubCategoryName = subcat.SubCategoryName, .CategoryID = subcat.CategoryID, .CategoryName = cat.CategoryName}

Comment: Public Function List() As ??????????????  

will be

Public Function List() As MyObject

is right???

Comment: That is correct.  The idea that this is leaning towards is to use custom objects as your view models, rather than coupling your views to your data model directly.

Comment: Why are your setters private?  Nothing outside your class will be able to set them if they're private.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is just telling you that you have declared Private Set on SubcatName and yet ypou are trying to assing a value to it after New Myobj().

For a first run you can declare a POD class (plain old data - just public data, no methods or properties) and once you see it runnung you can go tweaking it, adding methods etc.

If it's really important that all properties are read-only you'll need to try making your querying method a static member of the same class.

Also, there is a way to return anonymous type and cast it back to equivalent anonymous type declared at the receiving side. Got to move on to C# though :-)

Example ([read article](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx)):

```
// Method that returns anonymous type as object
object ReturnAnonymous()
{
  return new { City="Prague", Name="Tomas" };
}

// Application entry-point
void Main()
{
  // Get instance of anonymous type with 'City' and 'Name' properties
  object o = ReturnAnonymous();

  // This call to 'Cast' method converts first parameter (object) to the
  // same type as the type of second parameter - which is in this case 
  // anonymous type with 'City' and 'Name' properties
  var typed = Cast(o, new { City="", Name="" });
  Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, City={1}", typed.Name, typed.City);
}

// Cast method - thanks to type inference when calling methods it 
// is possible to cast object to type without knowing the type name
T Cast<T>(object obj, T type)
{
  return (T)obj;
}
```