# How to cast an anonymous type to IQueryable<Order_Detail>?

Tags: c#, wcf, odata

I am creating an `OData` service method in which I have written the following code:

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Order_Detail> getByYear(int year)
{
    var dc = new NorthwindBigEntities();
    var query = from p in dc.Order_Details
                where p.Order.OrderDate != null && p.Order.OrderDate.Value.Year == year
                select new
                {
                    TotalSales = p.UnitPrice * p.Quantity,
                    Product = p.Product.ProductName
                };
    return query;
}
```

but I am getting an exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable CustomMethod.Order_Detail'.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `select new` do `select p`. Currently you are selecting anonymous object and you can't convert it to `System.Linq.IQueryable CustomMethod.Order_Detail`

You can't project to `Order_Detail` since it appears to be a class of framework. Since you are doing calculation in your anonymous object, You can either return `IQueryable<Order_Detail>` by `select p` and do the calculation later on LINQ to object, or you may create a new class and project to that. If you end up creating a new class then you should modify your signature as per class name.

```
public IQueryable<Order_Detail> getByYear(int year)
{
    var dc = new NorthwindBigEntities();
    var query = from p in dc.Order_Details
                where p.Order.OrderDate != null && p.Order.OrderDate.Value.Year == year
                select p;
    return query;
}
```

If you create a new class like:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public string Product {get;set;}
    public double TotalSales {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can do

```
public IQueryable<MyClass> getByYear(int year)
{
    var dc = new NorthwindBigEntities();
    var query = from p in dc.Order_Details
                where p.Order.OrderDate != null && p.Order.OrderDate.Value.Year == year
                select new MyClass
                {
                    TotalSales = p.UnitPrice * p.Quantity,
                    Product = p.Product.ProductName
                };
    return query;
}
```

Considering **its a service returning data, its better if you create your own class** and return only the required properties. You should also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460831/linq-to-sql-return-from-function-as-iqueryablet)

Comment: Hello Habib, I have modified my code according to your suggestion but I am still geting same error.

Comment: @RudreshBhatt, What approach you are trying ? did you create new class ?

Comment: I have created a new class as you suggested but I was not successed. only the error changed "can not implesitly cast IQueryable<MyClass> to Linq"

Comment: did you change your query from `select new` to `select MyClass` ?