# How cast System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery type to System.Collections.Generic.List type?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two simple Lists:

```
public partial class Visitor
{
    public Visitor()
    {
        this.Visits = new HashSet<Visit>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PermitId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Visit> Visits { get; set; }
}

public partial class Visit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int VisitType { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime VisitDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Visitor_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Visitor Visitor { get; set; }
}
```

In WCF method i wrote query and tried to return result:

```
public List<Visitor> AllVisitors()
        {
            using (var te = new TurnstileDbEntities())
            {
                te.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;


                return (List<Visitor>) te.Visitors.SelectMany(visitors => te.Visits
                    .Where(o => o.Visitor_Id == visitors.Id)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(), (visitors, visit) => new {visitors, visit});
            }
        }
```

Well, as expected, I received an exception:

> Additional information: Failed to cast the type of object
>   "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[TurnstileWcfService.Visitor,TurnstileWcfService.Visit]]"
>   to type
>   "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TurnstileWcfService.Visitor]".

Ok. I rewrite this.
Declare new class.

```
public class JoinResult
{
    public Visitor Visitors { get; set; }
    public Visit Visits { get; set; }
}
```

And rewrite method.

```
   public IQueryable AllVisitors()
    {
        using (var te = new TurnstileDbEntities())
        {
            te.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            return te.Visitors.Join(te.Visits, 
                r => r.Id, a => a.Visitor_Id, (r, a) => new JoinResult
            {
                Visits = a,
                Visitors = r
            });
        }
    }
```

It is works but i want use Visitor class. Visitor class contain ICollectionVisits and i want populate it. How can I do this in Linq statement without declaration of new class?

Also I can get what i want in following code. But I don't like this.

```
var visitors = te.Visitors.ToList();
foreach (var item in visitors)
{
      item.Visits = te.Visits.Where(v => v.Visitor_Id == item.Id).ToList();
}
```

Comment: on the first glance [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734320/how-to-cast-an-anonymous-type-to-iqueryableorder-detail-in-c) might help

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `Include` method: `te.Visitors.Include(v => v.Visits)`.

Comment: @GertArnold: Visits is a virtual property. Shouldn't it be included by default? It was included when I ran my test.

Comment: You disabled `ProxyCreationEnabled`, so no lazy loading.

Comment: I get exception when ProxyCreationEnabled = true because models generated from EF. I wrote about it yesterday  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565418/failed-to-invoke-the-service-when-the-method-returns-listt

Comment: @GertArnold : I missed ProxyCreationEnabled = false. Another lesson learned.

Comment: With loop i get another exception - Circular Reference error when serializing objects. But that's different lesson too.

Comment: When serializing data, it's always better to disable lazy loading and to `Include` what you need to be included. As for the circular reference, you have to tell the serializer to ignore them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh241056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. Better still is to use DTOs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gert Arnold is right, try:

```
List<Visitor> visitors = te.Visitors.Include(v => v.Visits).ToList();
```

**Edit** I got it to work as follows as well:

```
List<Visitor> visitors = te.Visitors.Include("Visits").ToList();
```

Comment: Yes. Now it's great. But as I said above, another exception occured. Circular Reference error when serializing objects.
Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear this part works. Please mark it as an answer, and I will take a look at your other error.